# How to use PHP mysqli() in a non-object oriented environment

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

I have the following connection file...

```
<?php
session_start(); 

// Create new mysql connection object
$DBConnect = @new mysqli("localhost","root","","Ladle");
?>
```

which I include in the following script...

```
<?php ob_start() ?>
<?php session_start() ?>
<?php
//Connects to the database
include("inc_LadleDB.php");
$this->DBConnect = $DBConnect;

// Get the e-mail address entered
$email = $_POST['user_email'];

$sql = $this->DBConnect->mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblEmployees WHERE fldEmail='".
                            $email."'") or die(mysql_error());

$Result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

//validate email fo valid maine account
if($Result)
{ ...
```

I tried running this but got an error of "Using $this when not in object context"; I just need to perform simple queries and don't want to deal with OO PHP but I have no choice now that mysql is deprecated. How can I reference the included connection file to run the SELECT query in this no OO file?

Comment: `mysql_*` != `mysqli_*`, you can find solution in [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) in example #1-> Procedural style

Comment: You can't mix calls to `mysql_*()` with calls to `mysqli_*()`. Use `mysqli` alone, since `mysql` is deprecated.

Comment: Question to OP: Doesn't the mysqli documentation show how to call all the functions procedurally? Where did you get the idea that you HAVE to use OO to use them?

Comment: @Barmar my bad, I didn't notice the manual had a section on OO and procedural calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this` is a keyword reserved for Classes in PHP. Since you're running the queries in a procedural manner, there's no need for the `$this->` prerequisite.

You can easily use the `mysqli` object inside your code as follows:

```
$DBConnect = new mysqli("localhost","root","","Ladle");

// Get the e-mail address entered
$email = $_POST['user_email'];

$sql = $DBConnect->query("SELECT * FROM tblEmployees WHERE fldEmail='".
                            $email."'");

$Result = $DBConnect->fetch_assoc($sql);

//validate email fo valid maine account
if($Result)
{ ...
```

For reference, using `@` to surpass errors is a bad habit to get into. You should really handle errors using `try { } catch() { }` blocks.

Secondly, your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) - so it might be wise for you to look into [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: To the phantom downvoter, please explain as well, rather than just recklessly clicking the downvote button. This also applies to Barmar's answer...

Comment: Quite contrary. try { } catch() { } blocks should NOT be used to handle an error message

Comment: So you'd recommend surpassing them over `try { } catch() {  }`?

Comment: @BenM thank you, this clarifies quite a lot, I wasn't able to find anything that explained this elsewhere!

Answer (score 1):

Just because mysqli provides an OO interface, it doesn't mean that *your* code has to be written in OO style. You can just use ordinary functions and variables in your application.

```
$email = $DBConnect->real_escape_string($_POST['user_email']);

$sql = $DBConnect->query("SELECT * FROM tblEmployees WHERE fldEmail='".
                        $email."'") or die($DBConnect->error);

$Result = $sql->fetch_assoc();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing OO and functional calls, which is causing you confusion.  The `mysql_*` functions are not the same as `mysqli_*` functions, so everywhere you have `mysql_*` is wrong.

Also, don't do this: `DBConnect->mysql_query`.  DBConnect is an instance of MySQLi, so just call `DBConnect->query`.